# Cómo imprimo un vector al lado de una matriz? En C

Tags: array, c, matrices, imprimir

Hasta ahora tengo esto. Necesito que el Vector Horarios se posicione al lado de la matriz Dias. Hasta ahora me muestra bien la matriz.

Sería

```
            FRANJA     L  M  M  J  V  S  D
             M  0     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
             T  0     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
             N  0     0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

El código es:

```
int main ()
{   int Dias[3][8]={0}, Horario[3]={0};




    MostrarListado(Dias,Horario,3,7,3);


    return 0;
}

void MostrarListado (int D[][7], int H[], int cf, int cc, int v)
{   printf("FRANJA   Lu        Ma        Mi        Ju        Vi        Sa        Do\n\n");
    int f, c, i;

    for(i=0;i<v;i++)
    {  printf("",H[i]);
    }
        for(f=0;f<cf;f++)
        {   for(c=0;c<cc;c++)
            printf("         %d",D[f][c]);


            printf("\n\n");

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ocupas combinar los ciclos de tu función `MostrarListado` de modo que quede la impresión del vector simultanea a la matriz.

```
for(f=0;f<cf;f++)
{
   printf(" %i",H[i]);
   for(c=0;c<cc;c++){
      printf("         %d",D[f][c]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");
}
```

Esto solo imprimirá los valores del vector si quieres que también se muestren las letras ocupas crear otro vector, para almacenar las letras o directamente sobre el código colocar alguna sentencia de impresión de letras.

Ejemplo:

```
for(f=0;f<cf;f++)
{
   switch(f){
      case 0:
         printf("M ");
         break;

      case 1:
         printf("T ");
         break;

      case 2:
         printf("N ");
         break;

      default:
         break;
   }
   printf(" %i",H[i]);
   for(c=0;c<cc;c++){
      printf("         %d",D[f][c]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");
}
```